# `Expectation` of a positive random variable gives negative results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

Using `Expectation` to find $E[\operatorname{score}^2]$ evaluates to $-\frac{1}{6}$ below, why is this happening?

```
dist = ChiSquareDistribution[1];
shiftedDist = TransformedDistribution[x + t, x \[Distributed] dist];
pdf = PDF[shiftedDist, x];
score = D[Log@PDF[shiftedDist, x], t];
Expectation[score^2, x \[Distributed] shiftedDist] (* -1/6*)
```

I was using this to compute Fisher Information, and the wrong answers appear to happen for distributions with bounded domain, except for Uniform, where Expectation and NExpectation results coincide

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
fisher[dist_] := (
   shiftedDist = 
    TransformedDistribution[x + \[Theta], x \[Distributed] dist];
   pdf = PDF[shiftedDist, x];
   score = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(Log[
      PDF[shiftedDist, x]]\)\);
   Block[{\[Theta] = 
      0}, #[score^2, x \[Distributed] shiftedDist] & /@ {Expectation, 
      NExpectation}]
   );

pairs = {
   {"cauchy", CauchyDistribution[]},
   {"normal", NormalDistribution[]},
   {"student-t", StudentTDistribution[1]},
   {"half-normal", HalfNormalDistribution[1]},
   {"arcsin", ArcSinDistribution[{-1, 1}]},
   {"Semicircle", WignerSemicircleDistribution[1]},
   {"MarchenkoP", MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]},
   {"Exponential", ExponentialDistribution[1]},
   {"Chi2", ChiSquareDistribution[1]},
   {"uniform[0,1]", UniformDistribution[]},
   {"uniform[-1,1]", UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]},
   {"bates", BatesDistribution[2]},
   {"weihbul", WeibullDistribution[1/2, 2]}
   };

TableForm[fisher[#[[2]]] & /@ pairs, 
 TableHeadings -> {First /@ pairs, {"fisher", "fisher n", 
    "variance"}}]
```

Comment: -1. I see two syntax mistakes in your code: (i) `x` denotes the distribution `ChiSquareDistribution[1]` and  the variable of   `PDF[shiftedDist, x]`; (ii) `score=D[Log@PDF[shiftedDist, x], t]` is not any distribution at all.

Comment: Up to [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Fisher+information&title=Special:Search&ns0=1), Fisher information depends on  a parameter, but `ChiSquareDistribution[1]` has no parameter. The Maple's code `with(Statistics):
eval(FisherInformation(ChiSquare(n), 1, n), n = 1);` results in $1/8\,{\pi}^{2}$.

Comment: @user64494 the stats part is discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637361/efficiency-of-chi-squared-denoising), but regardless of how Fisher Information is defined, expected value of a positive variable shouldn't be negative

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such a non-constructive manner. I repeat there are two syntax errors in your code. That's all.

Comment: Good observation about whether the distribution is bounded.  From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information:  One of the required regularity conditions is "The support of f(X; θ) does not depend on θ."

Comment: I think this question will be closed due to not recognizing the details of the statistical theory.  However, why *Mathematica* gives a negative answer when it should give a "does not converge" answer seems a legitimate question to me.  My guess is that all of the resulting "Piecewise" functions confuse *Mathematica*.

Comment: @user64494  I don't see any syntax errors.  (i) `x` doesn't purport to denote a distribution, and (ii) `score` is a random variable and, of course, is not a distribution: `score` doesn't need to be a distribution.

Comment: @JimB Fisher Information is defined for uniform, those regularity conditions are for Cramer-Rao bound I believe, that wikipedia page is half-baked

Comment: The rough rule is that the parameter shouldn't appear in the endpoints where the density is positive.  For your example with the shifted chisquare it does.

Comment: About your deleted comment:  I think you're right.  The conditions are probably sufficient but not absolutely necessary.  (It's been a long time since I looked at that.)

Comment: @JimB: I mean distribution as random variable.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: You wrote "the stats part is discussed here". Sorry,  I don't see any definition of the Fisher information there.  Can you kindly give us a reference to the definition of the Fisher information by fisherInfo = Integrate[score^2  pdf, {x, t, ∞}]? TIA.

Comment: @JimB ok, actually I think perhaps rule of thumb for endpoints is that positivity of **derivative** of density at endpoint causes problems. IE, adding 3 uniform gives well-behaved density w.r.t Fisher Information formulas. So does adding 5 chi-squared. But 2 uniform (`BatesDistribution[2]`) or 4 chi-squared is problematic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if the following explains the issue:

```
dist = ChiSquareDistribution[d];
shiftedDist = TransformedDistribution[x + t, x \[Distributed] dist];

pdf = PDF[shiftedDist, x][[1, 1, 1]]
(* (2^(-d/2) E^((t - x)/2) (-t + x)^(-1 + d/2))/Gamma[d/2] *)

score = (D[Log@PDF[shiftedDist, x], t] // PiecewiseExpand)[[1, 1, 1]]
(* (-2 + d + t - x)/(2 (t - x)) *)

fisherInfo = Integrate[score^2  pdf, {x, t, ∞}]
(* ConditionalExpression[((-2 + d) Gamma[-2 + d/2])/(8 Gamma[d/2]),
     Re[t] > 0 && Im[t] == 0 && Re[d] > 4]
fisherInfo = FullSimplify[fisherInfo]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/(2 (-4 + d)), Re[t] > 0 && t == Re[t] && Re[d] > 4] *)
```

We see that we need $d>4$.  So consider the following table:

```
Table[{d, 1/(2 (-4 + d))}, {d, 1, 6}] // TableForm
```

[image: Table of Fisher information statistics]

It appears that *Mathematica* is not considering the restriction that $d>4$.

Comment: JimB (@ does not work): Can you kindly give us a reference to the definition of the Fisher information by `fisherInfo = Integrate[score^2  pdf, {x, t, ∞}]`? TIA.

Comment: Thanks for the `PiecewiseExpand` trick. Looks like `Expectation` takes some shortcuts, turning some other expectations into integrals in this way (`WeibullDistribution[1/2, 2]`) gives expected results

Comment: @user64494 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information.  Under certain conditions (mentioned on that webpage) either the expectation of $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\log f(X;t)\right)^2$ or $-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\log f(X;t)$ can be used (and result in the same value).

Comment: @JimB: Thank you . See my answer.

Comment: My comment about the possibility of closing this question because of statistical theory issues was wrong.  Sorry about that.  It does now appear that it's a *Mathematica* issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a calculation of the Fisher information for `ChiSquareDistribution[d]`. We start from

```
pdf = PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[d], t]
```

> `Piecewise[{{t^(-1 + d/2)/(2^(d/2)*E^(t/2)*Gamma[d/2]), t > 0}}, 0]`

Now, according to [the definition of the Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Fisher+information&title=Special:Search&ns0=1),

```
FI = Integrate[D[Log[pdf], d]^2*pdf, {t, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions -> d >0]
```

> `1/4 PolyGamma[1, d/2]`

and

```
FI /. d -> 1
```

> `Pi^2/8`

Comment: What is incorrect in my answer? To downvote without any  comment is not fair.

Comment: Note that table listed in question computes Fisher Information of TransformedDistribution with respect to shift parameter $t$ for various base distributions